# How can I display foreign key data in a datagrid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework 6 with a code first approach. The code below is simplified version of the entity classes I'm working with.

```
public class Complaint
{
    public int ComplaintId { get; set; }
    public int RemarkId { get; set; }
    public string ComplaintName { get; set; }

    public virtual Remark RemarkNavigation { get; set; }
}

public class Remark
{
    public int RemarkId { get; set; }
    public string RemarkText { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Complaint> ComplaintsReverseNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

Next I'll query the database with Linq.

```
var complaints = db.Complaints
    .Where(x => x.ComplaintId == 1)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .ToList();
```

Then I'll use the extension method `ToBindingList()` in order to track any changes made. Like so...

```
var complaintsBindingList = db.Complaints.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Finally I'll display the data in a data grid. Unfortunately any foreign key data will not be displayed correctly as seen in this picture.

[image: Datagrid Example]

How then can I display the `RemarkText` from the `RemarkNavigation` in the data grid?

Comment: Have you tried with `Include()` clause like `db.Complaints.Include(x=>x.RemarkNavigation)`?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot I had tried that, see my answer.

Comment: Good you figured out. But if you had posted markup for grid someone might have figured it out earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to display my data. I turned `AutoGenerateColumns` to false. Then I explicitly created the column like so.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="TestColumn" Binding="{Binding RemarkNavigation.RemarkText}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

From the looks of it `AutoGenerateColumns` won't generate values that are multiple levels down.